How to force PHP to use the new ImageMagick version?
Been at this for about 2 hours now, read about 20 articles on Google.  Fired everything I had into the terminal and its still not working.  Restarted Apache and PHP-FPM several times.
My Server configuration:
CentOS 7
PHP Version 7.4.33
VPS hosting
Imagemagick 6.9 is currently working but I need to install version 7 to access the newer functions.  Got the newer 7.1.1 version "installed", but PHP is still using the old version.  When I run the command:
convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-33 Q16-HDRI x86_64 22263 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.8)
output from phpinfo():
imagick module version  3.7.0
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2024-01-12
Any ideas how I can force PHP to use the newer version?  Tried reading a bunch of articles about how to delete Version 6.9, but some of the commands aren't working.  I believe alot of the information out there is for Ubuntu while I'm running CentOS and that's why basic commands aren't working, such as:
sudo phpdismod imagick
sudo apt remove php-imagick
When i run those commands, I get errors like this:
sudo: apt: command not found
Been at this for about 2 hours now, read about 20 articles on Google.  Fired everything I had into the terminal and its still not working.  Restarted Apache and PHP-FPM several times.
[EDIT]
I've upgraded my server to AlmaLInux 9 (with cPanel), and mostly the same problem. I'm running PHP 8.1
I'm still stuck with Version 6.9. Trying to get PHP to use version 7.1
Here's what comes up with I do print_r(imagick::getVersion()); in PHP:
[versionNumber] => 1693 [versionString] => ImageMagick 6.9.13-11 Q16 x86_64 18407 https://legacy.imagemagick.org
Here's what comes up with I do convert --version in the shell:
WARNING: The convert command is deprecated in IMv7, use "magick"
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-33 Q16-HDRI x86_64 22263 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff webp x xml zlib zstd
Compiler: gcc (11.4)
Here's what comes up with I do magick -version in the shell:
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-33 Q16-HDRI x86_64 22263 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff webp x xml zlib zstd
Compiler: gcc (11.4)
So it seems like its installed on the server, but PHP still using the wrong version.
Spent another 3 hours on it last night installing and re-installing everything I could find. Is it true that I also need to install phpize and php-devel to get this to work? both of those software packages have been difficult for me to install. The server keeps rejecting my attempts to get them installed. I am at the ponit where I may have to download them manually to get them to install, but i can't even find a version that is compatible with AlmaLInux 9
Any ideas?

It seems you installed imagemagick for the command line, that's why you can run
convert --version

But you also installed an imagemagick php module (php-imagick or something) and that's why you see something about it in phpinfo(). That one has a different version.
I never tried php-imagick but I believe you can run both from php, however in a very different way.
For php-imagick, according to php doc you'd do something like
$im = new Imagick(); 
$im->{some methods}(...);

while with convert you'd just run whatever you'd run on the command line:
exec("convert -resize '1600x1600' 'path/to/input/file' 'path/to/output/file");

Both ways should be valid, if you choose to go for the command line, you'll get version 7.
If you choose to go for the php library, just look into upgrading your package into version 7.
Also note that "sudo apt remove php-imagick" doesn't work on Centos (that's for debian based distribution like ubuntu). Try instead "sudo yum remove php-imagick". If the package isn't found, try searching for it to get the exact name with "yum list installed | grep -i magick".

this would be an excellent approach, except I have a VPS account with Godaddy and I'm not sure exec is allowed.  Researched it a bit, and it seems like its a security concern?  Can you think of a way to circumvent this?

My host has disabled the following commands: exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
